# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' when using str(sum(list))

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sum

I'm going through the Python tutorial and have no idea why my code isn't working. I know I need to tell Python to print an integer manually but I have already put `str(sum(ages))`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
ages = ['24','34','51','36','57','21','28']

print('The oldest in the group is ' + str(max(ages)) + '.')

print('The youngest in the group is ' + str(min(ages)) + '.')

print('The combined age of all in the list is ' + str(sum(ages)) + '.')
```

Error:

```
File "list2.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('The combined age of all in the list is ' + str(sum(ages)) + '.')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you can't use `sum` on a list of strings. In order to do this, you can use a generator expression to convert each element to an integer first:

```
print('The combined age of all in the list is ' + str(sum(int(x) for x in ages)) + '.')
```

Which gives us:

```
The combined age of all in the list is 251.
```

Comment: Ok, thank you.

Do you know why this code does work?

wallets = [20,15,25,41]

print('The total amount of money is: ' + str(sum(wallets)))

Comment: That's why I'm confused. Why does that code work but using the same str(sum(ages)) not work for the code in the question?

Comment: @MauricePhilipps because the elements in `ages` are strings, and the elements in `wallets` are integers. Note the quotes around each element in `ages`.